# Use path variable in nodejs with query values in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using the express framework in node.js. I want to access both path variable and query parameters.when I used only path variable it works fine but with the query parameter it won't work suggest me the correct solution for use both in single API. Here I mention the code.

```
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var type = url_parts.params.id;
    Console.log('ID:', type);
    next();
}, function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('User Info');
});
```

Comment: Express automatically puts these values in `req.params` and `req.query` respectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `var url.parse()` you can directly pass the value from `req`

```
req.params.id
req.query.queu
```

For Example:

```
var type = req.params.id;
var query = req.query.q;
```